# Pivot a query with multiple unions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to edit a report but the users want the columns across the top of the page, due to its like that in the legacy application.

The query is very old but it work so don't really want to spend time rewriting the whole thing.
It has 12 unions.

To keep the example simple I've removed the joins and filters

```
SELECT 1 as num, 'Complaints' as Label SUM(1) as [count]
FROM complaints

UNION

SELECT 2 as num, 'Address' as Label SUM(1) as [count]
FROM Address

UNION 

SELECT 3 as num, 'Inspections' as Label SUM(1) as [count]
FROM Inspections
```

I can pivot a non-union queries (done it a couple of times) but can't think how to do this one.

Comment: Just use your existing query as a derived table (sub-query) to your pivot.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the result you expect to see here? This will help to get the Answer. What column of rows need to be pivoted and so all. @DaleK is  correct. you can use your query as a derrived table or use # table to then pivot.

Comment: Sorry didn't think to add that. Columns Label and Count - thats all that is needed

Answer (score 1):

The union query could be made into a common table expression (CTE) and then pivoted (or 'cross tabulated') using conditional aggregation.  Something like this

```
with union_cte(num, [Label], [count]) as (
    SELECT 1 as num, 'Complaints' as Label, SUM(1) as [count]
    FROM complaints

    UNION

    SELECT 2 as num, 'Address' as Label, SUM(1) as [count]
    FROM Address

    UNION 

    SELECT 3 as num, 'Inspections' as Label, SUM(1) as [count]
    FROM Inspections)
select max(case when [Label]='Complaints' then [count] else 0 end) [Complaints],
       max(case when [Label]='Address' then [count] else 0 end) [Address],
       max(case when [Label]='Inspections' then [count] else 0 end) [Inspections]
from union_cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM complaints) as complaints,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM address) as address,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inspections) as inspections;
```

This might be simpler than using the existing results, if the queries are as simple as they are in your question.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a play around with that.